# Passing multiple values to Core Data Migration Policy Function

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters to a Core Data Migration Policy function.

I have set up Mapping Model and Transformation policy as well as added another version of the model. I have added a new field called name and want to merge the fields title, firstname, and lastname, into it.

So far the function I have is this:

```
FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "transformCustomerName", $source)
```

And the method I have on the policy is:

```
-(NSString*) transformCustomerName:(Customer*) customer;
```

I am getting a break (exception with no details) in the code when the persistance store tries to update.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've solved it. The documentation on this stuff is pretty sparse but here is what I did:

```
FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "transformCustomerName:::", $source.title, $source.firstname, $source.lastname)
```

and

```
-(NSString*) transformCustomerName:(NSString*) title :(NSString*) firstname :(NSString*)lastname;
```